# Can self ever be false or nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can `self` ever evaluate to false or nil?

For example...

```
class FooBar

  ...

  def check_this
    self && check_something_else
  end
end
```

Is the `self &&` in this conditional necessary?

Comment: I don't think so, the `self &&` likely does nothing, always truthy in my book.

Comment: No, not in this example. In Ruby, only `nil` and `false` evaluate to false in a boolean / conditional expression. Since `self` here refers to an instance of `FooBar`, it can never be `nil` or `false`. (Note that these are instances of the singleton classes `NilClass` and `FalseClass`, respectively.) The only exception would be if you are opening up `NilClass` of `FalseClass`, which I take it you are not doing.

Comment: @jformoff, opinions are not helpful. If you have an argument for your assertion, we'd like to hear it.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz, what if we have `FooBar = NilClass` before `class FooBar...`? :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland -- ah, yes, sneaky, I see I have not yet reached pure ruby ascension, thinking about classes as if they were like Java classes! Still, in that case you could never instantiate a new `FooBar` since `NilClass` is singleton. And `self` would *always* evaluate to `nil` so the example conditional is still meaningless, just for a different reason :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Remember everything in Ruby is an object so `self` is falsy for `false` and `nil`:

```
nil.instance_eval { self }  # => nil
false.instance_eval { self }  # => false
```

Comment: Specifically, the only objects that *are* falsy are `false` and `nil`.

Comment: You're right, I've been in JS/Python land for too long.

Comment: Ooh. JS... that has the strangest truth/false rules.

Comment: Good Point.  So self can be false when opening up NilClass and FalseClass.  However I think in my example above `self` can still never evaluate to false.  (Although I guess now I'm splitting this post into two separate questions )

Comment: If you're writing code to extend `false` you're into some mad science territory.

Comment: @abaldwin99: It can't. Only `false` and `nil` can be false, and `self` isn't assignable. The only time `self` can be false is in the context of a method on `false` or `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but only under some very strange circumstances:

```
irb(main):001:0> def false.test
irb(main):002:1>   puts "hello" if !self
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> false.test
hello
=> nil
```

Comment: You don't have to go to that extreme; `self` is  `false` (`nil`) whenever the receiver is `false` (`nil`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I'm assuming you're referring to something like `false.instance_eval {puts self}`?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of demonstrating the assertion that `self` is false whenever the receiver is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

No, `self` can't be nil or false in normal code.

`nil` and `false` are Ruby objects with methods. `self` is `nil` and `false` respectively in those:

```
def nil.self
  self
end
nil.self
=> nil

def false.self
  self
end
false.self
=> false
```

This isn't exactly monkey-patching, it's defining singleton methods, although I bet it's not the normal case you were thinking of either.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [relevant article](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/) by Avdi Grimm on this subject, apparently it is not possible to make an object falsy unless in very odd circumstances like going after `NilClass` or `false` I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

```
class NilClass
  def selfie
    self
  end
end

nil.selfie #=> nil

class FalseClass
  def selfie
    self
  end
end

false.selfie #=> false
```

Comment: I gave this answer some time ago, but deleted it, thinking (incorrectly) it was the same as another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it can't because--if an object is nil or false--you cannot call a method on it because of it not belonging to the class.

Comment: Generally yes, technically no.

Comment: `nil` (`false`) is the sole instance of the class `NilClass` (`FalseClass`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland ... and as long as he does not extend this classes (do not remember what it was called in Ruby), NilClass ans FalseClass will not have the method he specified.

Comment: I see your point. The OP has asked two questions. #1: "Can self ever evaluate to false or nil?" (Same question as the title.) As other answers have demonstrated, the answer is "yes". #2 "Is the self && in this conditional necessary? (for the example)?". The answer is "no" because here `self` can never be `nil` or `false` (provided the constant `FooBar` does not evaluate to `NilClass` nor `FalseClass`).